# Sass divide does not work when using with sass function

Tags: css, sass

I have this function that converts px to em:

```
  @function em($pixels, $context: 16px) {
      @return #($pixles/$context)em
    }
```

I have variable that uses this function:

```
$margin: em(60px);
```

Now I am trying to use it like this:

```
div {
 margin: 0 -#{$margin / 2}; 
}
```

But this is invalid css. the output in the devtools is:

```
margin: 0 -3.75em / 2
```

When I removing the function and just use em value it's working.
How can I do this?

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think there is a typo in your function code but I am ignoring that because your function is working fine based on your output. The real ***problem is with the type of value*** that is being output by the function. Since you are ***just concatenating*** the `em` to the calculated value using interpolation, the ***output is a string and not a number***, so you cannot perform math operations on it.

Instead of concatenating the `em`, use multiplication by `1em` to append the units and now your original code would work fine.

```
@function em($pixels, $context: 16px) {
  @return ($pixels/$context) * 1em;
}
```

Comment: Now the output is: margin: 0 -3.75 * 1em / 2

Comment: @Developer123: Are you sure? Here is an online demo @ [Sassmeister.com](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/98bcebc1d8a71e2be87254bb6ac94c58) and it seems to work fine.

Comment: You're welcome @Developer123. I am removing that online sample to avoid clutter in my list of gists. Please don't mind :D

Answer (score 3):

What Harry said,
But when you use the variable, try it like this:

```
div {
  margin: 0 ($margin / -2);
}
```

Comment: Yea, that's also correct. I just left it as-is because there wasn't any extra math done on top of it, so just concatenation was ok.